# R code not sending email via task scheduler but otherwise runs fine

Tags: r, email, scheduled-tasks, sendmailr, rdcomclient

I have a R code which after doing a bunch of steps sends out an email in the end. When I run this on RStudio, the entire code runs fine and sends out the email. However, when I run this via Windows Task Scheduler, the code still runs fine (and does what is intended) but does not send out the email. I have tried both RDCOMClient and sendmailR, and the problem persists.

Here is how the task is scheduled.

Program/script: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe"
Add arguments: datavalv3.R
Start in: C:\BLP\Projects\Project_07

Here is the code part with the email (with RDCOMClient)

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_name <- file.path(mainDir, subDir)
subject <- paste0("Data quality checks completed for ", analysis_date)
body <- paste0("Data summary has been compiled for all the farms for ",    analysis_date,". All the data summaries are saved in the folder <", path_name, ">.")

email_fn <- function(recipient) {

  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  outMail[["To"]] = recipient
  outMail[["subject"]] = subject
  outMail[["body"]] = body
  outMail$Send()  

}

email_fn(recipient = "person1@abc.com")
```

Here is the code part with the email (with sendmailR)

```
library(sendmailR)  

from <- "person1@abc.com"
to <- c("person2@abc.com","person3@abc.com")
subject <- "Email Subject"
body <- "Email body."                     
mailControl = list(smtpServer = "tucson.websitewelcome.com")

sendmail(from = from, to = to, subject = subject, msg = body, control = mailControl)
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

This is an update: Figured out the problem. In the task scheduler security options, earlier I had checked "Run whether user is logged on or not". I un-checked this and checked "Run only when user is logged on" - this did the trick and the emails are going through.

Comment: Are you sure the library `sendmailR` is properly loaded, when the script is executed as Task Scheduler? I had similar problems, but on Linux, and the case was that I had installed a package in my personal folder, and when scheduler run it, it had no path to my personal folder to find the package. So maybe print result of .libPaths() as a normal user and as a Windows scheduler and compare.

Comment: Thanks @bartoszukm. The code utilizes 3 libraries (RODBC, data.table & sendmailR) and all these are there in the same path (in my user's folder). If RODBC and data.table are loading properly, can sendmailR still may not?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue Ankur?

Comment: Have similar issue. And in my case I need to tick the 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. Did you happen to find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

when you try to send emails by Task Scheduler, it's just skip that email portion due to some reason(not sure why).
Here is the trick, try using **taskscheduleR** Package. It will also send email even when you logged out. Please install other dependent packages as well.

```
install.packages('data.table')
install.packages('knitr')
install.packages('miniUI')
install.packages('shiny')
install.packages("taskscheduleR", repos = "http://www.datatailor.be/rcube", type = "source")
```

[image]